# Diagnosing sporadic mouse disconnects

Tags: logitech-mouse

My 10 year old Logitech G5 mouse started to experience random disconnects recently. The mouse loses power, then reconnects a few second later, usually when playing mouse-intensive video games.

The keyboard, and even another USB mouse I hooked up simultaneously work fine during these losses, and changing USB ports doesn't do anything. I can't reproduce the issue at will; pulling on or twisting the cord, banging the mouse around, and rapid clicking doesn't cause the disconnect. However it does happen when the mouse is rapidly used, it has never happened while causally browsing.

How can I diagnose what hardware problem the mouse is exhibiting?

Comment: Sounds like the mouse is simply failing.  If no other mouse you exhibits this behavior just replace it

Answer (score 0):

As @Ramhound states, it's likely a mouse hardware issue.

You can check using another machine to see if the issue recurs playing games -- if not reproducible at all, the issue could be due to an OS update or driver update on your PC, in which case back-out the update.

If the issue recurs on the other PC, it's likely mouse hardware.

- On the off-chance it's just dust, [you might open the mouse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBdRwn7GObc) and *gently* blow out the dust (careful with canned Freon or other high pressure source, which can blow loose small parts).
- Make sure all connectors are seated firmly.
- If a crack develops in a printed-circuit flat cable, it *might* be possible to fix it with conductive ink (e.g. automobile rear-defroster repair kit).

Answer (score 0):

Wired mice often fail develop a break just where the cable enters the mouse body. Its not a clean break and the strands can maintain some sort of connection because they overlap. I have had success in cutting the cable an inch or two from the mouse and reconnecting it inside the mouse. Match colour to colour. Small soldering iron essential!